# Description of “Logistics Domain” in AI

Tags: terminology, artificial-intelligence

While reading some papers in AI (for a project I have to do), I see expressions "blocks world domain" and "logistics domain". I know what blocks world domain is, but I don't know the definition of logistics domain.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what efforts you have made to try to answer this question on your own?  Have you Googled and looked for a definition of the phrase in a few standard AI textbooks? (may require a trip to the library...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logistics and Blocksworld are domains that are often used as examples in the field of automated planning and scheduling.

Logistics was used in the first international planning competition [IPC98](ftp://ftp.cs.yale.edu/pub/mcdermott/aipscomp-results.html). The description on this site says:

> There are several cities, each containing several locations, some of which are airports. There are also trucks, which can drive within a single city, and airplanes, which can fly between airports. The goal is to get some packages from various locations to various new locations. This domain was created by Bart Selman and Henry Kautz, based on an earlier domain by Manuela Veloso.

It is described in more detail in by McDermott:

D. McDermott, The 1998 AI Planning Systems competition, *AI Magazine* 21 (2), pp. 35-55. 2000.
[(paper)](http://www.aaai.org/ojs/index.php/aimagazine/article/viewArticle/1506)

A complexity analysis for this domain is in the follwing paper by Helmert:

M. Helmert.
Complexity results for standard benchmark domains in planning.
*Artificial Intelligence* 143 (2), pp. 219-262. 2003.  [(paper)](http://ai.cs.unibas.ch/papers/helmert-aij03.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, it refers simply to the field of [Logistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistics).